# Is there a longer alternative version of The Good The Bad and the Ugly?

Tags: alternate-version, the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly

According to IMDB, the theatrical release of The good, The Bad and the Ugly is 2hr 28mins long. This corresponds with the (old) DVD I have of the movie.

But I recently saw an online version that claimed to be 2hr 58mins long. Is that an alternative, longer, version? And, if it is, what are the key differences?

Comment: My copy (burned to HDD long ago) is 02:58:41 with no extras like director's interview or deleted scenes, 00:02:55 of opening credits and a surprising 00:00:30 of closing credits. Sorry, I cannot tell you what additions were included over the 02:28:00 version but I found [this](http://www.tcm.com/tcmdb/title/18724/The-Good-the-Bad-and-the-Ugly/alternate-versions.html).

Answer (score 3):

## Yes

> On 12 May 2009, the **extended** version of the film was released on Blu-ray. It contains the same special features as the 2004 special edition DVD, except that it includes an added commentary by film historian Sir Christopher Frayling.
>
> The film was re-released on Blu-ray in 2014 using a new 4K remaster, featuring improved picture quality and detail but a change of color timing, resulting in the film having a more yellow hue than on previous releases. It was re-released on Blu-ray and DVD by Kino Lorber Studio Classics on August 15, 2017, in a new 50th Anniversary release that featured both theatrical and extended cuts, as well as new bonus features, and an attempt to correct the yellow color timing from the earlier disc
>
> [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Good,_the_Bad_and_the_Ugly#Deleted_scenes) (which has a list of the previously deleted scenes)